# Can't get Time Machine over AFP/netatalk to work. Don't get drive as option

Tags: ubuntu, osx-lion, time-machine, afp, netatalk

I have read various howto's (http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/time-machine-on-a-network-drive/)  but not sure any were made for Lion.  I got the latest netatalk setup on Ubuntu, and see the drive in Lion Finder.  I created the sparsebundle and named it with my computer-name.sparsebundle but when I go into Time Machine->SelectDisk I don't get the option for my AFP drive.  What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that as of Lion, your AFP server must support DHX2 or SRP authentication. Make sure your installation of netatalk has DHX2 or SRP working (not just original DHX[1] which it seems like netatalk defaults to).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in the share listing in AppleVolumes.default there is a tm option to enable timemachime on the volume.